# NSMutableString in iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

How can I apply `uppercaseString` on `NSMutableString`? In this code the value in `string2` is not changing in second `NSLog`:

```
NSMutableString *string2=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:100];
[string2 appendFormat:@"%@ Objective C",@"Hello"];
NSLog(@"%@",string2);
[string2 uppercaseString];
NSLog(@"%@",string2);
```

Comment: `uppercaseString` returns a NSString, it doesn't apply the transformation on it.

Answer (score 0):

`uppercaseString` does not transform the current string to uppercase. what it does is that it returns a transformed uppercase string.

Here is the link to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1409855-uppercasestring) about `uppercaseString`

so to answer your question to be able to make string2 an upppercase what you can do is something like this:

```
// need the mutable copy since string2 is a mutable string and uppercaseString only returns an immutable copy
string2 = [[string2 uppercaseString]mutableCopy];
```